# Nested Attributes in Nested Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

`Devise 3.5.2` & `Rails 4.2.3`

Hello, all

I'm feeling at my wit's end with this one!

I'm trying to add nested attributes inside nested attributes on my devise sign-up form.

Basically, the user enters their contact info - Name/Phone (this works like a charm already). The contact fields are built using nested attributes from the Contact model.

However, I also want them to enter in 5 "zones", which are nested inside the Ownership model. The Zone model contains a "zip" column. I am trying to get 5 boxes that will generate 5 rows in the Zones table. I can't get any zone inputs on to my form.

So:

```
Sign Up!

First Name: <input>
Last Name: <input>
Phone: <input>
Zips: <input> <input> <input> <input> <input>
Email: <input>
Password: <input>
...<etc>...

             MEMBER
         ______|___________________
        |            |             |
     CONTACT      OWNERSHIP    (columns)
        |         ___|___________________________
    (columns)    |       |       |       |       |
               ZONE     ZONE    ZONE    ZONE    ZONE
                 |       |       |       |       |
             (column)(column)(column)(column)(column)
```

Member model:

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :role
  has_one :contact
  has_one :ownership
  has_many :zones, through: :ownership

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact, :ownership, :zones
```

*(Contact model is empty)*

Ownership model:

```
class Ownership < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :zones

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :zones
end
```

Zone model:

```
class Zone < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ownership
end
```

Registrations controller:

```
  def new
    build_resource({contact_attributes: {}, ownership_attributes: {zones_attributes: {}}})
    respond_with self.resource
  end
```

Registrations#new view:

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <%= f.fields_for :contact do |cf| %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= cf.label :first_name %><br />
      <%= cf.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= cf.label :last_name %><br />
      <%= cf.text_field :last_name %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= cf.label :phone %><br />
      <%= cf.text_field :phone %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <% if apply_domain? %>
    <%= f.label 'Zips' %>
    <%= f.fields_for :ownership do |of| %>
      <%= of.fields_for :zones do |zf| %>
        <div class="field">
          <%= zf.text_field :zip %>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <%= zf.text_field :zip %>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <%= zf.text_field :zip %>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <%= zf.text_field :zip %>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <%= zf.text_field :zip %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

...
~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

db migrations:

```
class CreateZones < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :zones do |t|
      t.string :zip
      t.references :ownership

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

~~~~

```
class CreateContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :contacts do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :phone
      t.date :dob
      t.string :gender
      t.string :street
      t.string :city
      t.string :state
      t.string :zip
      t.string :referrer

      t.references :member

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

~~~~

```
class CreateOwnerships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :ownerships do |t|
      t.references :member

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

~~~~

```
class AddOwnershipIdToMember < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
      add_reference :members, :ownership, index: true
  end
end
```

~~~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to repeat :zip text field 5 times in your view. You just need to write

```
    <%= f.fields_for :ownership do |of| %>
      <%= of.fields_for :zones do |zf| %>
        <div class="field">
          <%= zf.text_field :zip %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

and in your controller create new instances of objects, for example

```
resourсe.build_ownership
(1..5).each { resourсe.ownership.zones.new }
```

But there is a problem, that ownership doesn't have any id, so zones can't be associated to it. So you need to take care of it in your `create` action.